# Как получить из activity ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

У меня есть 2 activity, называется `screen1`, `screen2`. Я использую их, как фрагменты (но это не фрагменты, а просто activity), в котором есть `ImageButton`. `screen1`, `screen2` я бросаю в `viewFlipper`, который находится в `activity_main` для того чтобы сделать Sliding. У меня все получилось, Sliding работает, но... Кнопки никак не реагируют, потому что нет обработчика. Я хочу сделать обработчики этих кнопок в одном главном классе `MainActivity`. Вопрос в том, как мне достать из screen1, screen2 ImageButton и поставить им обработчики в главном классе?

Так добавил `screen1` и `screen2` в главный `activity_main`, в блок `ViewFlipper`

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int layouts[] = new int[] { R.layout.screen1, R.layout.screen2 };
    for (int layout : layouts){
        flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Не надо создавать новый вопрос с уточнением старого. Надо было в старый внести правку.

Comment: И у вас, кажется, не 3 активити, а одна. А остальное - это просто разметка некая, к активити отношения не имеющая... Вопрос всё ещё не совсем понятен.

Comment: По идее можно просто после добавления разметок во ViewFlipper чрез него же и искать его внутренности по их ID

Comment: Вот у вас есть MainActivity, к нему привязан XML-файл activity_main, некий контейнер других XML-файлов (но это не фрагменты, а просто разметки), которые заключены в блок viewFlipper, который находится в activity_main, для того, чтобы я смог сделать Sliding. Это все я сделал. Но кнопки, что находятся в screen1 они не работают, потому что нет класса. Я хочу использовать содержимое screen1 в ГЛАВНОМ КЛАССЕ MainActivity. КАк  мне это сделать?

Comment: У этих ваших кнопок есть ID?

Comment: Вы же видите все на скрине. btnGoogle, btnGMusic и т.д. Вот их хочу взять и манипулировать ими в главном классе MainActivity

Comment: Может как-то можно через layout inflater ?

Comment: LayoutInflater тут не нужен. И на скрине не видно есть ли у ваших кнопок ID (android:id="+@id/someId")

Comment: <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/google"
        android:id="@+id/btnGoogle" />

Вот один из них. В правом боку скрина посмотрите, видны же id IMAGE BUTTON

Comment: Есть же [`ViewPager`](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html), зачем выдумывать самодельные костыли, а потом ломать голову, как ими пользоваться ..

Comment: @pavlofff, согласен на счёт ViewPager, но в данном случае проблема в непонимании как обращаться со вьюхами, добавленными через `addView()`

Answer (score 2):

В активити вы можете получить ссылку на любой элемент её разметки по её ID. Даже, если вы добавили элементы вручную из другой разметки.

```
//после добавления во ViewFlipper
ImageButton btnGoogle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnGoogle);
```

Главное помнить, что если в разметках есть View с одинаковыми ID, то найдётся только одна из них, что может быть чревато ошибками.

И для подобной задачи есть ViewPager c фрагментами.

Comment: @Эдуард, если один из представленных ответов решает заявленную в вопросе задачу, то вы можете проголосовать за него и отметить "верным", воспользоввшись стрелками и "галочкой" слева от тела ответа.